# Restrict NAT in IOS to only one public IP

Tags: cisco, nat, ios

I've managed to enable port-forwarding on my Cisco 877 but I wasn't able to find a way to specify a single accepted IP from the outside. Any link to a Cisco documentation or commands to type in IOS are welcomed.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: By 'single accepted IP', do you mean one IP for all your inbound connections? Do you have any statics set up?

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of your current config?  (Interfaces, nat commands, access-lists if you have them.)

Answer (score 0):

"NAT" in and of itself won't disallow anyone.  It will do translation.  It sounds like you have set up a port forwarding to an internal device, but want to allow only 1 external device to use that particular port forward?